# How to check if dev is not null?

Tags: r

I have a function for ploting like this:

```
f <- function(x,y){  

  for (i in 1:10){

    png(getwd(), height=1500, width=500)
    plot(x,y)
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

everything is all right when I use:
`f(2,3)`
but if I use `f(2,"a")` then the function is breaking before `dev.off()`

I can place `on.exit(dev.off(), add=T)` on the begening of the function but then in normal execution I will `dev.off()` too much 1 time.

I think the solution is to put sth like this to the function:

```
 on.exit(if(dev != NULL) dev.off(), add=T)
```

but how to check that `dev != NULL` ?

Comment: how to use that `dev.list()` This doesnt work:  `on.exit(if(exists(dev.list()) == T){ dev.off()}, add=T)`

Comment: OK, `on.exit(if(is.null(dev.list()) == F){ dev.off()}, add=T)`  this is OK ?

Comment: a is nothing, f(2,a) should return mistake.

Comment: while (!is.null(dev.list()))  dev.off()

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the following technique:

```
if (length(dev.list()!=0) {dev.off()}
```

this is actually an efficient technique to check the returning values of many other functions too, for instance, to check if `grep` finds something:

```
if(length(grep("me","I am not here"))==0) {print("not found")}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Where would you put the missing `)` in your first line? It seems to me that `if (length(dev.list()!=0))` and `if (length(dev.list())!=0)` (before and after `!=0`) gives the same result.

Comment: In fact, do we need to do the `!=0`? The `if` function interprets the output of `length` as a boolean. E.g. `length(1:3)` will return `TRUE`.

Comment: I missed putting the second close parenthesis in the If section after !=0 which should be exactly!=0))

Comment: This was a trick litterally independent of the output type of function as it works out by checking the length of output. So, if you need to check an actual value then it won’t work for you.